# Stored procedure on AIX environment and DYNAMICRULES BIND

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, aix

I'm writing a stored procedure (on AIX environment) and I need to activate "DYNAMICRULES BIND" selected.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE jjjjjj_PROVA 
( IN p_input1   CHAR(2) )
    LANGUAGE SQL
         SPECIFIC jjjjjj_PROVA
         DYNAMICRULES BIND
P1: BEGIN   
  ...
  ...
END P1
```

In the distribution phase I get the following error.

```sql
xxxxx.jjjjjj_PROVA - Distribuzione avviata.
Creazione di procedura memorizzata restituzioni SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
xxxxx.jjjjjj_PROVA: 12: An unexpected token "BIND
P1" was found following "DYNAMICRULES".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56
An unexpected token "BIND
P1" was found following "DYNAMICRULES".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56
xxxxx.jjjjjj_PROVA - Distribuzione non riuscita.
xxxxx.jjjjjj_PROVA - Rollback completato correttamente.
```

The same statement in the DB2 Z / OS environment is correct.

Tips?

Thank you!!

Comment: If you are attempting to compile that procedure on Db2-Linux/Unix/Windows,  then that syntax is not valid for SQL PL procedures.  For Db2-LUW, you can specify dynamicrules for stored procedures that need a precompile.  Different syntax rules apply for Db2-Z/OS and Db2-LUW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CALL SET_ROUTINE_OPTS('DYNAMICRULES BIND')` statement before `CREATE PROCEDURE` in the same session.
[Customizing precompile and bind options for compiled SQL objects](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0006584.html)